# How come v [index] < v [index - 1] returns true if index == 0?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

[Link to the function image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M1bBO.jpg)  Wrote a function to find an index of a pivot element(starting/lowest) in 
  sorted & rotated array. I worked through the problem and was checking for

edge cases and it even works for cases where index is zero. Could anyone

explain why/how v [index] < v [index - 1] returns true where index is

zero

Here is function progression:

[1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ]
  Checking: 5, this is low & high:0, 8
  Checking: 2, this is low & high:0, 3
  Checking: 1, this is low & high:0, 0
  Index of the pivot: 0

[7 8 9 1 2 3 4 5 6]

...
  Index of the pivot: 3

Comment: Sorry I could not get the indentation working so my code is below:<br/>int func(vector<int>&v, int low, int high){
    if(v.size()==0){
        return -1;
    }
        if(low<=high){
            int mid = low+(high-low)/2;
            
            if(v[mid] < v[mid-1]){                     // < -- here
                return mid;
            }else if(v[mid]<= v[high]){
                return func(v, low, mid-1);
            }else{
                return func(v,mid+1, high);
            }
    }
}

Comment: Undefined behaviour; `index - 1` is before the start of the vector.

Comment: What did you expect it to return? Whatever expectation you had it's wrong, because this is a case of undefined behaviour.

Comment: @john I expect it to return index of the smallest element and if the array is sorted it is supposed to return 0. It returns correct answer for any search, if I am not mistaken. But I'm confused how v [index] < v [index-1] returns true. I'll read up on "undefined behavior of vectors"

Comment: The behaviour is undefined.   That means, according to the standard, any result is correct, whether the result is something you think makes sense or not.   The result you get in  particular case will depend on what (if anything) is located in memory before the array `v` - and that depends on other code in your program, the compiler, optimisation settings, or even phase of the moon.   Simply accessing `v[index-1]` gives undefined behaviour, then all bets are off.   The result you get can be true, false, a program crash, or reformatting your hard drive - any of these, and more, is possible.

Comment: @NozimN It seems a lot of new programmers have trouble understanding the concept of 'undefined nehaviour', but it means exactly what it says. The C++ standard defines the behaviour of correct C++ program. But for most incorrect programs it defines no behaviour at all. So if you write an incorrect program your compiler is allowed to generate code that does anything at all. This lack of requirements on incorrect programs is one of the things that allows C++ compilers to generate fast code, because they don't have to include checks to catch errors.

Answer (score 2):

If index is 0 and you are trying to get value if index -1 it means that you are trying to access memory which does not belong to your array/vector. It is undefined behaviour. Don't do that

Comment: I understand what you mean, but I don't understand why is it returning true

Comment: @NozimN that's the meaning of undefined behavior, you get true now doesn't mean you cannot get true at all. You could get false even a crash from the same code

Comment: @NozimN Anything can happen with undefined behavior.

Comment: @NozimN That's just how undefined behavior works. It doesn't have to make sense.

Comment: Also, @NewMe, you misspelled "undefined". I'd suggest an edit, but I don't think there's anything else I'd change, so it'd be under the character limit.